# Where am i going wrong with my recursive binary search?

Tags: python

```
def BinarySearch(aList, first, last, target):

    assert 0 <= first < len(aList); last < len(aList)

    if len(aList) == 0:
        return False
    pos = first + last / 2
    pos = round(pos)
    if aList[pos] == target:
        return pos
    else:
        if target <= aList[pos]:
            return BinarySearch(aList[:pos], first, pos, target)
        else:            
            return BinarySearch(aList[pos +1 :], pos + 1, last, target)
```

This is a school problem and the arguments are input through another function. The test function passes an array with 6 values and my code finds the first 3 but not the last ones.

Comment: Think about what happens to the indices of the remaining elements if you slice the list.

Comment: im at a loss. my thoughts are that because the length of the array is smaller i will need to change the arguments in my recursive calls. if so im not sure what to.

Comment: Does `aList[:pos]` include the value at `pos` or not?  Hint: it works an awful lot like `range()`.

Comment: When you do `aList[pos +1 :]` you get a new list whose indices start at `0` again, but you pass in `pos+1` as the `start` argument. You should pass in `0` instead and adjust the `last` argument to `len(aList[pos +1 :]) - 1`. Also note that your `assert` statement only checks `0 <= first < len(aList)`. Because `last < len(aList)` is separated by a `;` it's just a no-op. You might wan to connect them via `and`. If you did your method would also raise an `AssertionError` upon the `BinarySearch(aList[pos +1 :], pos + 1, last, target)` call.

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
def BinarySearch( aList, first, last, target ):

    if first < 0 or last < 0 or first > last or first >= len(aList):
        return -1

    if len( aList ) == 0:
        return -1
    pos = (first + last) // 2
    if aList[pos] == target:
        return pos
    elif aList[pos] > target:
        return BinarySearch( aList, first, pos - 1, target )
    else:            
        return BinarySearch( aList, pos + 1, last, target )
```